# Cannot type accented capital letters in kde-konsole

Tags: keyboard, konsole

If i try to type a capital letter with accent (e.g. `Ř`) in kde-konsole, I get the following result: `ˇR` - the letter and the accent as two characters. The normal behaviour is that after pressing `ˇ` character, it is not output immediately but another character is expected. In the konsole tho, the character is output immediately. In other applications, it works fine. I am using gnome and in it the kde-console application. Any directions how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

First check your font (Right click, `Edit current profile`),

Then check your encodings, i.e `$LANG $LANGUAGE $LC_ALL` see if it's right,

Also check the encoding in Konsole profile (Advanced tab)

Does it happen to other KDE app like `kate, kwrite`?

Comment: Font should ok be as I can copy the character in the console - just can't type it. By default I use en_US.utf8 locale but switching to mine does not help. Encoding is utf8. But yeah it seems all kde packages on my computer have this issue. I tried konqueror and the same issue appear there (I don't have kate or kwrite).

Comment: hmm it does not work if konsole is run inside gnome. If I run it under kde (i have installed the whole desktop), it works correctly. Anyway at the process of trying it out in kde I again realized how incredibly cool this desktop environment is...

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be some kind of a bug refering to: [Keyboard layout does not work correctly in konsole](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=165543)
Set the keyboard-layout which you use mainly (that one which works fine in other applications) to the first position in kde keyboard-layout settings, or delete all other keyboard leyouts if you don't need them anyway.